# android ViewPager with ListViews that have "Swipe Right" to delete

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, listviewitem

My current android application has a number of ViewPagers.
One of these ViewPagers has three pages, each of which contains a ListView.
Each ListView allows "Swipe Right" on List Items for delete.
My Problem is Swipe Right not only swipes the ViewPager pages it also deletes listView items.
Is there a way to consistently recognize "different Swipe Right" gestures?
Or is the only solution to add Page Left and Page Right buttons for ViewPager paging, and leave swiping gestures for delete List Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the current page of view pager and disable swipe of this page . So you have  only swipe right of list view.